# How to search for text in a mysql column and also include punctuation

Tags: mysql, regex

My sql search utilizes the regular expression:

```
$sql = " select * from table where regexp CONCAT('[[:<:]]', :searchTerm, '[[:>:]]') ";
```

:searchTerm is a bound search variable.

Currently, If execute my search for the term "well", a bunch of results come up.  However, if I search for "Well,"  with a comma, the query result is empty.

I am assuming that this happens because '[[:<:]]' and '[[:>:]]' are word boundary markers, and thus, all punctuation is ignored.

Does anyone know how I can structure the query to also include punctuation?

Comment: remove the word boundaries . OR if the punc comes at the last then remove the second word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in punctuation character class `[:punct:]` to match a punctuation character followed a `?` which will match zero or one of the character or character class before it -- in this case it would be the character class you defined.

For example:

```
$sql = "select * from table where regexp CONCAT('[[:<:]]', :searchTerm, '[[:punct:]]?[[:>:]]') ";
```

Here's fair warning, I don't have much experience with MySql and I didn't text out the example above. This should work, or at least point you in the right direction. You can find out more about the [Regular Expression Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) section of the mysql documentation.

Additionally, I'm not sure what characters are included in the built-in punctuation character class, but you can define your own using square brackets  and just include the punctuation characters you want. For example `[,.!?;:]`

Comment: Hi there, I trued using the [[:punct:]] but that never worked, By defining my own punctuation do  you mean select * from table where  table.content regexp CONCAT('[[:<:]]', :searchTerm, '[[,]]?[[:>:]]')";

Comment: @PaulPreibisch Yes, that's what I meant. Your example just includes a comma (`,`) character, but it can include multiple characters between the square brackets. The regular expression will match on any one of the characters between the square brackets.